Is there a computable operation that minimizes entropy?
I have recently experimentally learned that decorrelation does not necessarily imply good compression, but good compressions have the effect of data decorrelation.
Since I cannot use autocorrelation as a metric of how well I'll be able to compress data (minimize its entropy), is there a mathematical way to pre-process it (filter it) such that its Shannon entropy is minimized?
I am working with a simple 1D array of numbers (16 bit stream of integers from an electron detector).
Thank you.

Have you tried zipping the file? If there are no known properties of the signal that you can exploit, it's unlikely that you can do significantly better than zip.  If  you CAN make reasonable assumptions about the file, your best compression strategy will depend on these assumptions.

I think it must be hard to find a lower bound on how much a vector can be compressed without placing limits on the complexity of the encoding and the amount of information you allow pre-defined at the encoder site.

"Since I cannot use autocorrelation" Why? your problem sounds very well-suited for that. A high degree of correlatedness directly translates to good compressability. A high degree of uncorrelatedness translates to it probably being hard to compress. I wrote the same under your last question already, I think!

@KnutInge I think this is the point where things get philosophical, because the act of searching for a good estimate for compressability is pretty central to many modern compression algorithms themselves … this question sounds a bit like "how can I do compression, before I do my compression? Because I want to make my compression easier!".

Would it be possible to talk a little bit more about what are you trying to achieve?

@A_A After some time, I believe I'm now able to formulate my question better. I'm trying to minimize Shannon's entropy with respect to the parameters of a 1D convolution that is being applied to a certain 1D discrete signal.
